# Does $ | X | = | \mathbb{R} |$ hold for all Banach spaces $X$?

Tags: set-theory, banach-spaces, cardinals

I remember reading somewhere that the cardinality of a Banach space $X$, denoted $|X|$ is equal to that of the continuum, but couldn't find it.

If this is true, the set of all bounded functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with the uniform norm, which I'll denote with $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ should not be a Banach space, since its cardinality is equal to $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})| > | \mathbb{R} |$.
Is this true?

I think that showing that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ is a Banach space like this:
It is clear that it is a normed space with the uniform norm since the functions are bounded.
Now take a Cauchy sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$.
Then for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $N_{\varepsilon} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that  $\| f_n - f_m \| < \varepsilon$.
The only candidate for a limit $f$ of this Cauchy sequence is the pointwise limit $f(x) := \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$.
How can I continue the proof, if the statement is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the cardinality of a nontrivial Banach space is at least $\mathfrak{c}=\lvert\mathbb{R}\rvert$, but can be bigger.  For example, let $S$ be a set of cardinality $>
\mathfrak{c}$ equipped with the counting measure, then $\ell^1(S)=L^1(S)=\{f\colon S\to\mathbb{F}\mid \sum_{s\in S}\lvert f(s)\rvert=:\lVert f\rVert<\infty\}$ has cardinality at least $\lvert S\rvert>\mathfrak{c}$ given by coordinate indicator functions.

I think what you misremembered is

> The cardinality of a nontrivial *separable* Banach space $X$ is $\mathfrak{c}$

The proof is to use the countable dense subset $S$.  There are $\lvert S^\mathbb{N}\rvert=\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ sequences from this countable dense subset, and each element of $X$ is represented by some Cauchy sequence from $S$, so $\lvert X\rvert\leq\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak{c}$.  Since $X$ needs to contain a copy of $\mathbb{R}v$ for some nonzero $v\in X$, we have $\lvert X\rvert=\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: Is the space $(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}), \| \cdot \|_{\infty})$ a Banach space?

Comment: Yes $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ is the same as $L^\infty(\mathbb{R},\text{counting measure})$.  $\ell^1(S)=L^1(S)$ is where only countably many nonzero, sum of absolute value is finite.  And there are no nontrivial (separable or not) Banach space of cardinality strictly *smaller* than $\mathfrak{c}$ because it needs to contain $\mathbb{R}v$ for a nonzero $v$,